# How to update bundler, gem-wrappers gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile

How to update bundler, gem-wrappers gems in my Gemfile. The following gems are shown as outdated but I don't see a direct reference to them in the Gemfile.

```
gem outdated

    bundler (1.7.3 < 1.7.7)
...
    gem-wrappers (1.2.4 < 1.2.7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming that you don't have an dependency issues) You can run a bundle update or In your Gemfile, you can remove the version numbers or get the specific version you want, and then do a bundle update.

And if you do specifically need those versions' then I guess you need to prefix the commands with `bundle exec` and let the bundler manage the dependencies. For example `bundle exec rspec spec/..`.

Comment: I don't want to do a "bundle update" as that will update all my dependencies and I am doing this in a controlled fashion for certain gems which are problematic.

Comment: Well, if you have the versions specified in your Gemfile , like 'bundler', '~>1.7.3' , then bundle update won't update it. If you don't have versions specified, then I guess you have to `gem install bundler --version 1.7.7`. and then specify that version in the `Gemfile` and do a bundle install so that the Gemfile.lock is updated

Comment: How about gem-wrappers?